# program exited with code 132

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

i am using raspbian,opencv-2.4.8 and geany this is my simple/first code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main ()
{
    Mat image=imread("/home/pi/Desktop/pic3.png");
    if (! image.data)
    {
        cout<<"error"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        namedWindow("display",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        imshow("display",image);
        waitKey(0);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

these are compile and build commands in geany->project->properties->build

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags opencv-2.4.8) -c "f'
g++ $(pkg-config --clfags --libs opencv-2.4.8) -o "e" "f'
```

and it compiles and build perfectly but when i execute it this is my output

Illegal instruction

---

(program exited with code :132)

i have searched this exit code on internet but couldn't find a single thread or issue about it

Comment: If you put all warnings on, you should see, you're missing a `return` statement for your error path.

Comment: i added -Wall( for both compile and build) to enable warnings but still the same result

Answer (score 20):

132 = 128 + 4

man exit:

```
>128   A command was interrupted by a signal.
```

man -s 7 signal

```
SIGILL        4       Core    Illegal Instruction
```

**Later**

The `-I/usr/local/include -I/usrlocal/include/opencv` makes sense for the compile-only (`-c`) call (but not for the second `g++` call which links the executable). But libraries aren't specified by their full paths. What you normally do, is to specify one `-L/usr/local/lib` (or similar) for each directory, and `-lopencv_calib3d` (or similar) for each library in those directories (omitting `lib` and `.so`.)

Comment: i am totally new to raspbian and i cant figure out why this error is generated even if i am using sample code of opencv same error appears any suggestion how to find/debug this error

Comment: i added sudo to my execute command now illegal instruction is gone but still gives   program exited with code 132

Comment: The commands you give for building look very strange to me. For instance: `"f'`. The `-c` switch requests "compile only", so there should be an .o file, but this isn't used in the next command. So, I guess `"e"` (why the quotes?) is the executable, `e`, compiled and linked by the second command. - It is required to know what the `$(pkg-config...)` returns; library names should go to the end of the compile/link commands.

Comment: its for geany "f' compiles the file which is opened and "e" creats .o file with same name

Comment: pkg-config returns '-I/usr/local/include -I/usrlocal/include/opencv /usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so' and so on all .so files @laune

Comment: Added some comments on compiling and linking.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but same result Illegal Instruction @laune

Comment: i don't think my problem is compile or build it, executable file is generated and when i execute it using ./test then i get this error

Comment: Compiling and/or building can be the problem - e.g., when you have managed to install compiler or a library that contains instructions not supported by that CPU. It's possible to make gcc display its details. - Does openCV support Raspberry?

Comment: yes, people are working on opencv + raspberry pi [http://robertcastle.com/2014/02/installing-opencv-on-a-raspberry-pi/] . [http://mitchtech.net/category/tutorials/raspberry-pi/] @laune

Comment: Well, leavin openCV aside, can you compile and execute a "hello world" C++ program?

Comment: yup it runs perfect @laune

Comment: The logical conclusion is that something's wrong with the library. The links you've given above aren't working any more.

Comment: my bad there was an extra "]" at the end of both links they are working and i will try a fresh reinstall lets see....